# how to get data by using ID in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use **angular-resource.js** file in my demo .I am retrieving
data from json file using $**resource**  and display my data using ng-repeat .But Each item I added one button (**info text button**).I need to get it infomation  using **$resource** property.I am sending ID on click function .but when I am using $resource property it gives error to me

```
 $scope.getIn=function(id){
     // alert(id)
      $scope.oneUser = Entry.get({user: id});
      console.log($scope.oneUser)
    }
```

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/lB11oQkQjbILK36u8V25?p=preview

Comment: Well, `$resource` is meant to work with REST APIs but you are trying to get something from a JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly what you are trying to achieve this should solve it:

```
  angular.module('app',['ngResource']).controller('a',function($scope, GetData){
    // read data from factory and store it in $scope.posts 
     GetData.then(
        function successCallback(data) {
             $scope.posts = data.data;
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
           console.log(response); // handle any errors
        });

    // buttonclick to return the values from the selected id
      $scope.getIn = function(id){
        angular.forEach($scope.posts, function(value) {
          if(value.id === id)
          {
            $scope.selectedValue = value;
          }
        })
      };

    console.log($scope.posts)
  })
  .factory('GetData', function($http){ // use http to read the json
    return $http.get('data.json');
  });
```

And the html:

```
  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller='a'>
    <div ng-repeat='p in posts'>
      <span>{{p.name}}</span>
      <button ng-click=getIn(p.id)>info</button>
    </div>
    {{selectedValue}}
  </body>
```